# gcloud command completion for zsh adds extra (breaking) escape characters

Tags: gcloud, zsh

How do I get `gcloud compute ssh` to stop adding unnecessary escape characters for spaces when I use command-line completion? For example, when I type `gcloud compute ssh` and then hit `<tab>` this is what I get:

```
greg@elfland ~> gcloud compute ssh
dbclone-gcp\ --zone=us-central1-a             joints-io-vbxq\ --zone=us-central1-a          joints-web-ffq1\ --zone=us-central1-f
joints-cron-538-2\ --zone=us-central1-a       joints-io-vvkx\ --zone=us-central1-a          joints-web-hk3c\ --zone=us-central1-b
joints-cron-tp1m\ --zone=us-central1-a        joints-prod-haproxy\ --zone=us-central1-a     joints-web-hqtf\ --zone=us-central1-b
joints-customer-vps\ --zone=us-central1-a     joints-prod-mariadb1\ --zone=us-central1-a    joints-web-jqfm\ --zone=us-central1-c
joints-io-0fsq\ --zone=us-central1-a          joints-prod-mariadb2\ --zone=us-central1-a    joints-web-pph5\ --zone=us-central1-f
joints-io-538-2\ --zone=us-central1-a         joints-prod-rabbitmq-1\ --zone=us-central1-a  joints-web-qvs5\ --zone=us-central1-a
joints-io-6dtn\ --zone=us-central1-a          joints-prod-truenas\ --zone=us-central1-a
```

If I try to use one of the options, it does not work due to the escape `\` of the space char:

```
greg@elfland ~> gcloud compute ssh joints-io-vvkx\ --zone=us-central1-a
Unable to find an instance with name [joints-io-vvkx --zone=us-central1-a].
For the following instance:
 - [joints-io-vvkx --zone=us-central1-a]
choose a zone:
 [1] asia-east1-a
 [2] asia-east1-b
 [3] asia-east1-c
 [4] asia-east2-a
 ...
```

which is asking for the zone, which is silly because the command is trying to flag the zone with `--zone=`. Of course, due to the escape `\`  of the space char, `gcloud` is treating the entire string as a hostname (`[joints-io-vvkx --zone=us-central1-a]`). If I remove the `\` char, then it works as expected:

```
greg@elfland ~> gcloud compute ssh joints-io-vvkx --zone=us-central1-a
External IP address was not found; defaulting to using IAP tunneling.
Warning: Permanently added 'compute.2162772965953140468' (ED25519) to the list of known hosts.
[greg@joints-io-vvkx ~]$
```

My `rc` files have

```
# The next line updates PATH for the Google Cloud SDK.
if [ -f '/Users/greg/Applications/google-cloud-sdk/path.zsh.inc' ]; then . '/Users/greg/Applications/google-cloud-sdk/path.zsh.inc'; fi

# The next line enables shell command completion for gcloud.
if [ -f '/Users/greg/Applications/google-cloud-sdk/completion.zsh.inc' ]; then . '/Users/greg/Applications/google-cloud-sdk/completion.zsh.inc'; fi
```

If that is any help. In addition, this is my version information:

```
greg@elfland ~> gcloud --version
Google Cloud SDK 448.0.0
bq 2.0.98
core 2023.09.22
gcloud-crc32c 1.0.0
gke-gcloud-auth-plugin 0.5.6
gsutil 5.25
```